# Group array items using underscore

Tags: arrays, underscore.js

I have six items in my array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. I would like to group array items per 3 items like that: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]. Is it possible with underscore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your array element.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      group = 3,
      result = arr.reduce((r,v,i) => {
        let index = Math.floor(i/group);
        (r[index] = r[index] || [])[i%group] = v;
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```